# How do I search for multiple records in a search form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I am trying to allow the user to be able to choose multiple records in a field on the search form.

Something like this:

```
<%= f.input_field :neighborhood_id, collection: Neighborhood.order(:name), :url => autocomplete_neighborhood_name_searches_path, :as => :autocomplete, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :class => "span8" %>
```

It sends it to my `search` model like this: `@search = Search.create!(params[:search])`

This is what the `Search.rb` model does with it:

```
key = "%#{keywords}%"
listings = Listing.order(:headline)
listings = listings.includes(:neighborhood).where("listings.headline like ? or neighborhoods.name like ?", key, key) if keywords.present?
listings = listings.where(neighborhood_id: neighborhood_id) if neighborhood_id.present?
listings
```

The issue is that this is just accepting 1 `neighborhood_id`, so I am getting this error when I choose multiple objects:

```
undefined method `to_i' for ["Alley Park, Madison"]:Array
```

Where `Alley Park` and `Madison` are the names of 2 neighborhoods, not the IDs.

So how do I get this working?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

The issue seems to not be in the lookup of the `params[:search]` per se, but rather in the conversion of the form input to an array of entries. I tried changing the search method to be something like:

```
listings = listings.includes(:neighborhood).where("neighborhoods.name like ?", neighborhood_id) if neighborhood_id.present?
```

Don't get hung up on the fact that I am looking up `neighborhood.name` and passing in `neighborhood_id`. I just did that because I know that the params for the field `neighborhood_id` were actually the names of the `neighborhood`. If this had worked, I would have refactored some stuff, but it didn't. So don't get hung up on that.

But that still returns the error `undefined method 'to_i'....`

Also, I still get that error even if I just pass in 1 option.

Comment: you can go through it by adding a join table between search and neighborhood.  to get the ids of the neighborhoods, you can define a setter for the names and get the ids of the neighborhood on that setter method.

Comment: Care to show me an example with some code?

Answer (score 1):

```
listings = listings.where("neighborhood_id in (?) ", neighborhood_id)
```

Comment: Isn't that effectively what I have now?

Comment: In the search params, it is still sending the names of the `neighborhood`, not the ID - i.e. `"search"=>{"neighborhood_id"=>["Alley Park,Madison,"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id instead of neighborhood names from the input field like this:

```
<%= f.input_field :neighborhood_id, collection: Neighborhood.order(:name), :url => autocomplete_neighborhood_name_searches_path, :as => :autocomplete, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :class => "span8", :input_html => { :id => "neighborhood_id" } %>
```

Comment: You have to loop through the array as it contains the collection of ids. The statement `key = "%#{keywords}%"` contains array which you can split and loop through each one to get each id.

Comment: But...I am not using `key` in my `neighborhood` lookup. That corresponds to a field that is commented out and not being used right now. Also, when I am looking through the params sent, I am not seeing  a collection of IDs in the params. This is what the params for `search` looks like: `"search"=>{"neighborhood_id"=>["Alley Park,Madison,"], "num_bedrooms"=>"", "num_bathrooms"=>"", "min_price"=>"", "max_price"=>"", "boro_id"=>"", "property_type_id"=>""}`

Comment: What about this query: `<%= f.input_field :neighborhood_id, collection: Neighborhood.order(:neighborhood_id), :url => autocomplete_neighborhood_name_searches_path, :as => :autocomplete, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :class => "span8" %>`. The idea is replacing name with id to get ids in search params. Making changes in query itself should work.